# Emulate shared row locks in Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to somehow emulate shared row locks (as they exist in other DBMS, like PostgreSQL) in Oracle DB?

That is row locks, that allow other session to obtain the same (shared) locks on the same row, but prevent them from obtaining exclusive locks. Also, an existing exclusive lock on a row prevent others obtaining any kind of row lock.

For reference: Oracle supports only exclusive row locks.

Note: The question is about Oracle DB 11.2g

Comment: If you explain what you're trying to do, maybe someone can tell you how it's done with Oracle.

Comment: Seconded. Oracle does have mechanisms for implementing alternative locking strategies, but it's hard to suggest anything without knowing what business logic you're trying to achieve.